# "... for length", is it a common pattern?

Tags: grammar

[A post](https://ieltssharebox.com/how-to-get-high-score-in-ielts-speaking-band-9.html) says

> Part 1 questions are often familiar and easy so you don’t have to give a long and difficult answer, just range from 1 to 3 sentences **for length**.

I understand the meaning of the sentence, I just want to know the usage of "for length". It seems to be a grammar pattern. If it is, are there others, such as "for time", "for weight"?

Answer (score 1):

It's rather unidiomatic to say it like this.

> just use 1 to 3 sentences.

would be much shorter and clearer. I wouldn't trust a website about learning English when it's writing sentences like this one and the one you mentioned here: [Are "there are" and "there have" interchangeable?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/246910/18673) which clearly has a grammatical error.