# Are "there are" and "there have" interchangeable?

Tags: word-usage

A [post](https://ieltssharebox.com/how-to-get-high-score-in-ielts-speaking-band-9.html) says

> I like living in London because it’s where most of my family members and friends live and **there have** lots of things to do here.

I guess the following sentence means the same thing as the one above

> ... **there are** lots of things to do here

Are "there are" and "there have" interchangeable?

Comment: _There have_ is not normally grammatical, except in a perfect construction eg _There have been_ The post you quite is either an error, or written by a non-native speaker.

Comment: Having looked: it's clearly a mistake. I think it should be _**they** have lots of things to do here_.

Comment: You also need a comma before "and there are lots of things ..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, that sentence should have been

> ... **there are** lots of things to do here

as you mentioned. What @ColinFine says in the comments:

> ... they have lots of things to do here

is grammatically correct but makes less sense; why would one like living in London when *their family and friends* have a lot of things to do there?

Comment: Do you find the use of "here" at the very end a bit odd? OP said *" ... it’s where ..."* which is usually used when the person speaking is not in that place. If they were in that place, "... this is where ..." would make more sense, I guess. *"I like living in London because **this** is where most of my family members and friends live, and **we** have lots of things to do **here**."* Or *"I like living in London because **it’s** where most of my family members and friends live, and **there** are lots of things to do **there**."* I know this isn't relevant but for some reason it's bugging me.

Comment: That's a little bit odd indeed, but I can certainly see it happen while speaking. It's quite a long sentence after all.